# WPF Listbox highlight part of ListBoxItem element

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listbox, highlighting

I have a TextBox and ListBox. User can search ListBox elements from TextBox.

ListBox is bound to CollectionViewSource.

CollectionViewSource has Filter event handler, that filters elements based on text that user enters into TextBox.

My requirement is to highlight user entered text within TextBlock of ListBoxItem elements.

I was thinking of breaking TextBlock into several Runs objects and modify Background property of Run objects that need to be highlighted.

I think it is not possible to do with DataTemplates.

Is there easy way to accomplish this?

Thank You!

Comment: Can you give more detail as to "Text Parts"? Is it matching a whole textblock or text within a textblock? If you're trying to match parts of a text block and highlight it, you won't be able to do it without perhaps using a text run instead of a textblock. Please give more details and maybe a sample of your xaml.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look and let me know. Thank You for Your effort :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE: I have elaborated significantly on this subject in [this blog post](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/06/search-and-highlight-text-in-arbitrary.html).**

I don't think there's any easy way to do this, but here is how I would tackle this problem:

1. Define a view model for the items in the list. It should include properties to expose the text and define which part of the text should be highlighted (starting and ending indexes, basically).
2. When the user enters text in the search box, look through the view models and check for matches in the text. If a match is found, set the indexes appropriately. If a match isn't found, set the indexes back to -1 or whatever signifies no match.
3. In your view, set the `Background` of the `TextBlock`s to the indexes. Use a converter to convert the indexes into a `GradientBrush` that is bright yellow (or whatever) between the two indexes.

Here's how *I think* you can figure out the dimensions of the highlighted portions of the `TextBlock`:

1. Get a `TextPointer` via the `TextBlock.ContentStart` property.
2. Move to the start of the selection by calling `TextPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(indexOfStart)` using `LogicalDirection.Forwards`.
3. Move to the end of the selection by calling `TextPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(indexOfStart)` using `LogicalDirection.Backwards`.
4. Call `TextPointer.GetCharacterRect` to get the bounding `Rectangle` of the highlighted content.

To be honest, I'm not sure that last bit work. I'd have to try it for myself, and I may do that for a blog post.

**EDIT**: Just had time to try this for myself. It definitely works, although with slight changes to my logic above. Below is the code that demonstrates. Here is a screenshot:

[Screenshot http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/2969/searchx.png](http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/2969/searchx.png)

*Window1.xaml*:

```
<Window x:Class="TextSearch.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="_searchTextBox"/>
        <Grid>
            <Path Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0">
                <Path.Data>
                    <RectangleGeometry x:Name="_rectangleGeometry"/>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
            <TextBlock x:Name="_textBlock">Some sample text that you can search through by typing in the above TextBox.</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

*Window1.xaml.cs*:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace TextSearch
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _searchTextBox.TextChanged += _searchTextBox_TextChanged;
        }

        void _searchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var searchText = _searchTextBox.Text;
            var index = _textBlock.Text.IndexOf(searchText);

            if (index == -1)
            {
                _rectangleGeometry.Rect = Rect.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                var textPointer = _textBlock.ContentStart;
                textPointer = textPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(index + 1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                var leftRectangle = textPointer.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                textPointer = textPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(searchText.Length, LogicalDirection.Backward);
                var rightRectangle = textPointer.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                _rectangleGeometry.Rect = new Rect(leftRectangle.TopLeft, rightRectangle.BottomRight);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the code is fairly self-explanatory. Obviously you will need to extend the concept to your particular scenario. You may prefer to leverage the `Background` property of the `TextBlock` combined with a `DrawingBrush` or `GradientBrush` instead of having the separate `Path`.

Comment: OK, I have my ViewModel. I'll try to start with Your idea. I will keep you updated with my progress. Thank You.

Comment: Wow. It will be pleasure to dig into the code. Thank You very much...I will let you know

Answer (score -1):

Filtering in WPF list box.
following Sample code work fine for me.

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="txtSearch" Height="21" Margin="63,12,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBox>
    <ListBox Name="listItems" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="22,0,0,44" Height="179" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

Vb.net Code

> binding the datatable into your Listbox

```
Dim _dtable As New DataTable("tblItems") _dtable.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
    _dtable.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    _dtable.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(Double))
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    For i = 100 To 110
        _dtable.Rows.Add(i, "Item " & i, 15.0)
    Next







  Private Sub Window1_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    listItems.DataContext = _dtable.DefaultView
End Sub
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
```

**_dtable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name like '" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"**

```
End Sub
```

> Above sample code Works for me

Comment: This does not address highlighting a portion of the item name.